# Find my custom code snippets Xcode 6?

Tags: location, xcode6, code-snippets

I know where the system default snippets are, but my two new ones cannot be found. Basically, I want to add in my collection of previous snippets. I made two new ones just to be able to find them. Didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Custom code snippets are stored in the following location:

```
/Users/YourUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me in Xcode 10, though it did for Xcode 9

Comment: @Adrian I haven't used the Xcode 10 betas. I recommend writing a new question.

Comment: Looks like they moved the access point around to it, but it's pretty much the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edKpCAWbPFA&vl=en One note, based on recently getting a new MBP is you might need to create a snippet to generate that directory...once you've created a snippet, that directory gets created and you can drop more snippet files into it.

Answer (score 3):

I used this for Catalina 10.15.5

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets
```